# Generating an auto-complete function Angular and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am currently working on a web application that makes use of :

1. JQuery
2. AngularJS
3. Kendo framework

In particular, I need to implement an auto-complete function using kendo on an input text.

So, my first option, was to select that input text using jquery and then apply the auto-complete to it like this :

```
$(".autoComplete").kendoAutoComplete({
            dataSource: data, 
            filter: "startswith",
            placeholder: "Select country...",
            separator: ","
        });
```

Where the auto-complete class is applied to an input element of type text.

However, it seems that this solution is not applicable seen that the input text is generated dinamically as an angular modal :

```
script type="text/ng-template" id="dialogAddCompany.tpl.html">
<div class="modal-header no-header"></div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"><div class="modal-caption-description-title"><label>{{tab.modal.title}}</label></div><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 caption-description"></div></div></div>

    <div ng-if="tab.modal.type === 'blackbox'">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                <label class="">Nome compagnia</label>
                <input class="autoComplete" />
                <input type="text"/> 
                // rest of the code
```

Looking on the internet, I found a solution to this problem using event delegation like this :

```
   $("#bubble").on("click", ".autoComplete",function() {

        $(".autoComplete").kendoAutoComplete({
            dataSource: data, 
            filter: "startswith",
            placeholder: "Select country...",
            separator: ","
        });
    });
```

Where #bubble is the id of a div that is already present on the page when it's loaded. 
**However this solution is not working. Any Idea how to solve this ? I have already tried to use a solution using angular like** :

```
<input type="text" kendo-auto-complete k-data-source="data" />
```

Where data is an array of data.

Thank you for your help!.

Edit :
I forgot to mention that the code I am talking about is inside a template like this :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="dialogAddCompany.tpl.html">
<div class="modal-header no-header"></div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"><div class="modal-caption-description-title"><label>{{tab.modal.title}}</label></div><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 caption-description"></div></div></div>

    <div ng-if="tab.modal.type === 'blackbox'" ng-controller="aipCompanyController">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                <label class="">Element</label>
                <input kendo-auto-complete k-data-source="data"/>
                <input type="text" ng-click = "clicked()" kendo-auto-complete k-data-source="data" />

                <!--<div ap-textbox ap-options="tab.cfg.textInput.options" ap-class="'form-control'" type="text" ap-value="tab.tabData.prova"></div>-->
```

If I try to create an input text with autocomple OUTSIDE of this template it works perfectly fine.

Comment: could you provide the code where you initialise/load kendo and angular, you need to make sure kendo is a dependency in your angular module for it work

Comment: @jigfox the code that I am talking about is part of a template inside the script tags. I have also tried to create an input text outside of the template and it works perfectly. I have edited the question for you to see the code better

Comment: that's not what I meant: I asked if you could provide more context, as how is your angular module initialised, how is kendo loaded, how is angular loaded, could you provide the code how you load kendo and angular, and how you add kendo to your module?

Answer (score 2):

With angular you should use the kendo-auto-complete attribute and bind to your data-source like this:

```
 <input kendo-auto-complete ng-model="yourModel" k-data-source="data"  />
 <p class="demo-hint">Your selection: {{ dataToShow }}</p>
```

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/angular

Comment: it should work, surely u have not registered the kendo ui in your angular configuration

Comment: you need something like this: `var app = angular.module("your-angular-app", [ "kendo.directives" ]);` in your code: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="dialogAddCompany.tpl.html">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <h4>Select Country /e.g. Armenia/</h4>
        <input kendo-auto-complete ng-model="country" k-data-source="countryNames" />
        <p>Your selection: {{ country }}</p>
    </div>
</script>

<a ng-click="currentTemplate='dialogAddCompany.tpl.html'">Load template</a>

<div ng-include src="currentTemplate"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
       .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
          $scope.countryNames = [
          "Albania",
          "Andorra",
          "Armenia",
          "Austria"];
});
</script>
```

Here I created a working example: https://dojo.telerik.com/AqEraMib

Answer (score -1):

You can find angular material implementation here:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

It's easy to understand and implement.

or you can watch this implement yourself:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4gZMJKAeWs